# Set scrapy built-in loggers at different level than user code logger

Tags: python, logging, scrapy

Scrapy built-in loggers:

- scrapy.utils.log
- scrapy.crawler
- scrapy.middleware
- scrapy.core.engine
- scrapy.extensions.logstats
- scrapy.extensions.telnet
- scrapy.core.scraper
- scrapy.statscollectors

are very verbose.

I was trying to set a different log level, DEBUG, than user spider log level, INFO. This way I can reduce the 'noise'.

This helper function works, some times:

```
def set_loggers_level(level=logging.DEBUG):    
  loggers = [
     'scrapy.utils.log',
     'scrapy.crawler',
     'scrapy.middleware',
     'scrapy.core.engine',
     'scrapy.extensions.logstats',
     'scrapy.extensions.telnet',
     'scrapy.core.scraper',
     'scrapy.statscollectors'
 ]
 for logger_name in loggers:
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    for handler in logger.handlers:
        handler.setLevel(level)
```

I call it from UserSpider init:

```
class UserSpider(scrapy.Spider):

      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          # customize loggers: Some loggers can't be reset a this point
          helpers.set_loggers_level()
          super(UserSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This approach works some time, others not.

What will be the correct solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can just set `LOG_LEVEL` appropriately in your `settings.py`, read more here: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-LOG_LEVEL

> **LOG_LEVEL**
>   Default: 'DEBUG'
>   Minimum level to log. Available levels are: CRITICAL, ERROR, WARNING, INFO, DEBUG. For more info see Logging.

If project wide settings are not focused enough, you can set them per-spider by using `custom_settings`:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    custom_settings = {
        'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',
    }
```

Source:
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider

Comment: LOG_LEVEL in settings is a wide scrapy project. I need set INFO level less verbose. Maybe some scrapy hack is needed here, more than a common setting

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say by "wide scrapy project", but if you need this set for a single spider, you can use `custom_settings` for the spider to set the same thing: `custom_settings = { 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO' }` for example. I've update my example accordingly.

Comment: I know `custom_settings` but I have only one spider. What I want is put all spider built-in logger at DEBUG level and spider logs called with self.logger.info at INFO level.

Comment: Hm, I didn't understand that's what you wanted. Wouldn't it make more sense to put built-in loggers at INFO, thus reducing the amount of DEBUG logs? The log level is the threshold that cuts out everything below that level. Having it set to DEBUG let's all logs through, which is what you are doing in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Settings different log levels per Log handlers is not very realiable.

At the end of the day the better approach will be launch scrapy cli tool from another script and filter logs output with a parser has needed.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same issue. I tried various method but it looks like since Scrapy uses logging module, you have to set it at global level which result in Scrapy to print all the debug information.

I've found more reliable solution to use bool flag with print statement fro DEBUG and use logger for INFO, ERROR and WARNING.